# Why is ftp_chmod() throwing a "Not implemented" error?

Tags: php, ftp, magento2, php-7.1

I am attempting to run the following code

```
$create_folder = ftp_mkdir($conn_jobcart,$folderName);

ftp_chmod($conn_jobcart, 0777, $folderName);
```

The file is created, but I lack write permissions, and I see a Warning in the logs:

> Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: ftp_chmod(): Not implemented. in /var/www/pcnametag_2.2.0/app/code/Avery/Maketostock/Controller/Adminhtml/Debug/Index.php on line 61

Comment: Could you perhaps provide the output of `ls -la`?

Comment: I think you ftp server don't support `SITE CHMOD` command

Comment: The `chmod` command is a non-standard FTP extension, not all servers implement it.